# Run a python script in a html based website with python packages

Tags: python, html, flask

I made a python chatbot which I want to implement in my HTML (+ CSS & js) website. I want to call the python file with an HTML button and the python file should return a variable (output string) which I could use to display the user on the HTML website.

- I've tried Brython, but I couldn't figure out how to import packages
  like nltk and tensorflow.
- I've tried flask, which works great, but the python file is the main
  file, who renders the HTML template. But that's not possible in my
  case. The HTML file should be the main file. And the website should remain
  on the same URL and, as far as I know (please correct me if I'm wrong),
  flask is URL based.
- I've tried translating all the python code into javascript manually,
  which worked but isn't a long-term solution for me.

So: what is the best way to run a python file with packages externally or internally in a HTML website without redirection?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: If you need to run any arbitrary Python code (such as ntlk or TF), there has to be a Python-based server your frontend app talks to.

Comment: Flask-socketio will allow you to do it without a redirect. If you want an example here is one: https://github.com/shoryamalani/templates/tree/master/flask/flask-socketio

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that HTML file is the main file you are loading the application using some server like nginx or apache? If yes, then why Flask is the problem? It seems that you could load data from Flask app using JS. You would still be on the same URL the JS would do everything in the background and possibly using JQuery you could render html components with data from Flask. (HTML based site loads content from Flask App using JS, the flask app is hosted somewhere else)
However as it is a chat application I would suggest something based on websockets.

The additional option could be to use webassembly for Python which is weird but theoretically possible.